# Why are the double vector elements being rounded up when printed?

Tags: c++

Basically I'm trying to print a vector of type double, but the print values are either rounded up or just weird. Maybe there's something I'm missing in the print statements since I'm not too familiar with vectors.

```
vector <double> abcd = { 123456789,554.55,13451.79 };

//print
cout << right << setw(75) << "Total Purchase:" << abcd [0] << endl;
    cout << right << setw(75) << "" << abcd [1] << "$" << endl;
    cout << right << setw(75) << "" << abcd [2] << "€" << endl;
```

Expecting them to be printed normally but the output for each is -

```
1.23457e+08     
554.55     
13451.8
```

Comment: See [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) especially the example.

Comment: what is "normally" ?

Comment: C++20 `std::format` can be more handy: https://godbolt.org/z/b7oEM7ob7 or `fmt` library.